# How to autocomplete file name with quotes by default in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I am working with file names that contains a lot of spaces.
For example, if I want to move a file `01 - Artist - Musique (explicit).flac` from the current folder to another, I begin to type :

```
mv O1<tab>
```

And I get the following completion :

```
mv 01\ -\ Artist\ -\ Musique\ (explicit).flac
```

I find this quite annoying to read and I prefer the format with quotes.

```
mv '01 - Artist - Musique (explicit).flac'
```

I can force the completion to use this format by putting a quote before my file name but I would like to make this behavior by default. I check the options of `shopt`, but I didn't found anything. Is there something I can do?